# How to use jquery to change stylesheet on keystroke combination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to use jquery to switch to a new stylesheet when a word is typed (not into a textbox, just typed)? I'm trying to create an easteregg on my site but am not really sure where to start with the stylesheet switching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/UYapL/2/

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('href', 'new.css');
    alert($('[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('href'));
});

// with keycontrols

$(window).keyup(function (e) { // (ctrl+i)
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 73) {
        $('[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('href', 'new.css');
        alert($('[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('href'));
    }
});
```

I am not sure if you are looking for something like this:

```
// for specific word g=71 e=69 o=79
$('body').append('<span id="code" style="display:none;"></span>');
$(window).keyup(function (e) {
  wrd = e.which;
  code = $('#code').append(wrd);
  if ($('#code').text()=='716979') { // geo
    $('[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('href', 'new.css');
    alert($('[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('href'));
    $('#code').text(''); // reset it here.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! If insead of ctrl+i, I wanted it to be when geo is typed (g=8 e=69 o=79), how would I go about changing e.ctrlKey && e.which == 73

Comment: If you're looking for a whole word, better to just test `$("#input").val()` to see if it contains `"geo"`.

Comment: @Barmar i'm not sure that's working for me, maybe because i'm not using any text boxes? it just needs to be typed onto the screen like a code, not into a box

Comment: Then your keyup handler has to append the characters to a string, and check the string each time to see if it ends with "geo".

Comment: Why use a DOM element to keep track of the typed word?  Why not just use a simple global variable?

Answer (score 1):

There are several parts to your question.

1. To listen for keystroke events that do not come from an input field, you can attach an event handler to the document object and listen for the `keypress` event and you can collect the keys that are typed by looking in the event data structure on that event.  In jQuery, you can use the `$(document).keypress(fn)` method.
2. To change styles, the simplest way is to just add a CSS class so some container and have a  set of style rules that change things when that class is present on the container.  This is way simpler and much easier to make work cross browser than actually changing style sheets.  In jQuery, you can just use the `$("#whatever").addClass("foo")` method.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<link id="css1" href="normal.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<script>
 if(something written)
  document.getElementById('css1').href = 'another_one.css';
</script>
```

`something written` is your check for click event or whatever you want

Comment: What would I be placing into (something witten)?

Comment: since i dont know what you mean what ``just typed, not into textbox``, i dont know what you are doing, so event handler depends on what you do and where you want to switch

Comment: sorry if it was a bit vague, i meant if say, "css" was typed on a website screen...not typed into a text field, just the keys pressed, like a konami code. So, if "css" is typed, the stylesheet will switch.

Comment: @cosm, oh now i got it sorry :). Jai gave more elegant answer, go for it pls